# XQuery – counting parent’s preceding siblings

Tags: xquery

I wish I could be able to count preceding siblings of the highest `div` in ePub (for a footnote). I need to pass the value to the attribute before passing notes through XSLT.

```
for $note in doc('/db/custom_jh/bukwor.xml')//tei:note[@place='bottom']
let $parent := count($note[preceding-sibling::tei:div[@n='1']])
let $update := update insert attribute att2 {$parent} into $note
return $note
```

Attempts with `$note[preceding-sibling::tei:div[@n='1']]` or `$note[ancestor-or-self::tei:div[@n='1']]` returns just `0` or the total sum of all the divs.

Something like `<xsl:number level="any" select="tei:div[@n='1']/>"` from XSLT, if possible.

**UPDATE**
The very minimal code for counting (still not working, returns only 6 × `1`, should at least one `2`:

```
for $note at $count in doc('/db/custom_jh/bukwor.xml')//tei:note[@place='bottom']
let $parent := count($note[ancestor-or-self::*/tei:div[@n='1']])
return $parent
```

Comment: Post a sample XML with a concrete example of what you are trying to select. It makes it easier for us to experiment and validate solutions.

Comment: Please update the question with an example document, expected and current (wrong) output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole example was slightly bad. Finally, I restructured the whole thing. At the moment, I do it this way:

```
let $chaps := 
(
  let $countAll := count($doc//tei:note)
  for $chapter at $count in $doc//tei:div[@n='1']
  let $countPreceding := count($chapter/preceding::tei:div[@n='1']//tei:note[@place='bottom'])
  let $params :=
    <parameters>
        <param name="footnoteNo" value="{$countPreceding}"/>
    </parameters>
  return
    <entry name="OEBPS/chapter-{$count}.xhtml" type="xml">
      {
        transform:transform($chapter, doc("/db/custom_jh/xslt/style-web.xsl"), $params)
      }
    </entry>
)
```

The `count($chapter/preceding::tei:div[@n='1']//tei:note[@place='bottom'])` does the trick for me. (I need to collect all footnotes in one file and make backlinks to locations of their indexes in different files).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ePub format of XML and there is no sample XML provided so the requirement isn't clear, at least for me. But according to the title, you might want something like this :

```
let $parent := count($note/parent::*/preceding-sibling::tei:div[@n='1'])
```

basically counting preceding sibling `tei:div` from parent element of current `$note`, where the `tei:div` have `n` attribute value equals `1`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I am sorry I haven’t provided any code (I thought I is not helpful). The problem is notes can occur on any level of the text. Every of them has it’s own id but I need to pass someway the parent-chapter number or id to it before I could extract all of them to another file (for preserving of the information for backlinking). At the moment, the path provided still returns '0'. Testing file is here: [link](http://46.28.111.241:8081/exist/rest/db/custom_jh/bukwor.xml)